# How to integrate $\frac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$ without substitution?

Tags: integration

I'm able to do the integration by substitution $x=\tan\theta$. However, in the material from which I read about this integral, the integration had been done directly without indicating how. I feel like I need to rewrite the integrand into some alternative form and to do integration by parts. Please give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: I think you want to know how to solve the integral without trigonometric substitution because it would be near impossible to solve it without substitution

Answer (score 3):

No substitution at all?  Well, one way is "[lucky guess (of the general form) and check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz)".
Look for a solution of the form $p(x) (x^2+1)^d$ for some polynomial $p$ and
some number $d$. Since
taking the derivative of $p(x) (x^2+1)^d$ would give us a term involving $(x^2+1)^{d-1}$, we should try $d=-1/2$.  Now

$$ \dfrac{d}{dx} \frac{p(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \frac{p'(x)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} - \frac{x p(x)}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} = \frac{(x^2 + 1) p'(x) - x p(x)}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$$

so we want $(x^2+1) p'(x) - x p(x) = 1$.  A polynomial of degree $0$ won't work, so next we try degree $1$: $p(x) = a x + b$.  That would give us
$ (x^2 + 1) p'(x) - x p(x) = a - b x$, so we want $a= 1$ and $b = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\frac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}dx
{=\int\frac {x^2+1-x^2}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}dx\\
=\int\left({\frac {1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}-\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}}\right)dx\\
=\int\left({\frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+x\frac{-xdx}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}}\right)\\
=\int\left({\frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+xd\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)}\right)\\
=\int d\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)\quad[\text{By product rule.}]\\
=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+c}$$

Answer (score 1):

You might guess that the integral of $\dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$ involves something related to $\dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}$ simply by changing the exponent by $1$, and in particular if you are lucky might be something like $\dfrac {a+bx+cx^2}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}}$, which has the derivative $\dfrac{b+(2c-a)x+cx^3}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$.

To get $\dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$, matching coefficients then tells you that you want $b=1,2c-a=0,c=0$, i.e. that $$\int \dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} \, dx = \dfrac{x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}} + \text{ constant}.$$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(\dfrac{x}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} + \text{ constant})\ne\dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$

Comment: @OM I should have written $\int \dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}} \, dx = \dfrac{x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}} + \text{ constant}$ and now have - thank you. $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{x}{(x^2+1)^{1/2}} + \text{ constant}\right)=\dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$

Answer (score -1):

It's a simple integration. Your integration is $$\int \frac{1}{(x^{2}+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$ . Now take $x^{2}$ common from the denominator. So, your integration will become $$\int \frac{1}{x^{3}(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}})^{\frac{3}{2}}}dx$$ . Now substitute $\frac{1}{x^{2}}=t$. Now $\frac{-2}{x^{3}}dx=dt$ . So,$\frac{1}{x^{3}}dx=-\frac{1}{2}dt$. So, your final integral will become $$\frac{-1}{2}\int \frac{1}{(1+t)^{\frac{3}{2}}}dt$$ . Now substitute $(1+t)=u$, then $dt=du$ . Now your integration is very much easy and simple. Now try to solve.

Comment: Your question is very good @IncredibleSimon.